# Поставить маркер на PictureBox.Image (C#, VS, WF)

Tags: c#, winforms

Как прикрепить маркер (тоже Image) к PicureBox.Image?

Comment: отрисовать его поверх в фоновое изображение?

Comment: Да, я уже делаю через Paint event